# Random strange behavior

Tags: java, random

I've created just for fun this method to find out how long it takes until this random method goes into a loop and what the seed is when this occurs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int key = firstRepeatingSeed();
        Integer integer = map.get(key);
        map.put(key, integer == null ? 1 : integer+1);
      }
      System.out.println(map);
    }
  }

  public static int firstRepeatingSeed(){
    Random random = new Random();
    HashSet<Integer> loopDetector = new HashSet<>();
    while (true) {
      int gen = random.nextInt();
      random.setSeed(gen);
      if (!loopDetector.add(gen))
        return gen;
    }
  }
```

**These are the results:**

```
-1381274646=2,
 -1686548232=2,
 154051178=717,
 -381624123=1,
 -334394727=1,
 -1261880000=1,
 -1128634575=1,
 658182704=1,
 364776881=141,
 -1985197764=11,
 1266282155=13,
 -1108864769=1,
 266843583=9,
 -1939453764=2,
 349725186=4,
 1525333558=2,
 -106280330=1,
 -1865148662=1,
 -296326218=1,
 -84817968=2,
 332765684=1,
 -1181949977=1,
 -595175830=59,
 -206288251=1,
 -2043038133=1,
 1220626100=1,
 -541517940=1,
 1373871195=14,
 1890953100=3,
 -1529367891=1,
 -1022666507=3
```

My question is why does 154051178 and 364776881 show up so often?

Comment: please check https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-generate-random-number-in-java,

Comment: @JPRLCol I know how to generate random numbers in Java... I just think it is strange that they start to loop so strange when generating a random number and then set it as the seed for the next generated number

Comment: Good random number generators do different tricks to ensure they return as random numbers as possible, but (re)setting the seed looks like breaks this specific implementation. Rule of thumb, do not reset the seed. The algorithm will have safeguards to return a good distribution of numbers. If you want to know the _why_, I recommend you to take a look at the implementation.